# Connecting to github by https using user:pw@github.com/repo when pw ends with @

Tags: git, bash, url, github

I am using `GIT_REPO_URL="https://$GIT_ACCOUNT:$USER_PW@github.com/XXXX/xxx"` syntax.

Lately I have changed my password so it ends by @.

For example my password is 123456789@.

When I input my password it says. `Couldn't resolve host '@github.com'` Basically the repo url is now equal to `GIT_REPO_URL="https://myAccountName:123456789@@github.com/XXXX/xxx"`.

Does anyone know, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to "URL encode" the username and password. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986 for [percent encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1).

`@` will be encoded as `%40`, so the url would look like: `https://myAccountName:123456789%40@github.com/XXXX/xxx`

Here is a tool for this: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ or just use an ASCII table ;).

---

Alternatives would be to use a [git store](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5343146/3906760) for storing credentials, use the [.netrc file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5343146/3906760), or use SSH keys.

Answer (score 3):

Why not switching to ssh and get rid of the passwords?

---

Simply follow those steps and you will set up your ssh key in no time:

- Generate a new ssh key (or skip this step if you already have a key)
  `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your@email"`
- Once you have your key set in `home/.ssh` directory (or `Users/<your user>.ssh` under windows), open it and copy the content

---

#### How to add sh key to github account?

- Login to github account
- Click on the rancher on the top right (Settings)
  [image: github account settigns]
- Click on the `SSH keys`
  [image: ssh key section]
- Click on the `Add ssh key`
  [image: Add ssh key]
- Paste your key and save

And you all set to go :-)